# How to Execute the sql statement from a table and convert into html

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
 Declare @a varchar(max)
 Declare @b varchar(max)

 set @a = cast(( 
 SELECT td = f1, '', td = f2 , '' from tablenme Where f2 is null order by f1
 for XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS )AS nvarchar(max))      

  set @b ='<html>
 <body>
 <H3>Stayed on the list</H3>
  <table border = 1>       
  <tr bgcolor="#BBFFFF">
  <th> f1 </th> 
  <th> f2 </th>
  </tr> '

 set @b = @b + @a +'</table></body></html>'

 Print @b
```

I want to get the total select stmt used in above code from a table field.

```
`SELECT td = f1, '', td = f2 , '' from tablenme Where f2 is null order by f1`
```

I want to store the sql stmnt in a table field.

I have tried like this

```
 Declare @a varchar(max)
 Declare @b varchar(max)
 Declare @c varchar(max)
 Declare @sql varchar(max)

 set @a = 'cast(('
 set  @sql=(SELECT sql_query from table2) -- I have stored total sql query in a field of table2
 set @c = (' for XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS )AS nvarchar(max))')


  set @b ='<html>
  <body>
  <H3>Stayed on the list</H3>
  <table border = 1>       
  <tr bgcolor="#BBFFFF">
  <th> f1 </th> 
  <th> f2 </th>
  </tr> '

    set @abc= @a+@sql+@c
  set @b = @b + @a +'</table></body></html>'

  Print @b
```

But here @abc is taking as string, it is not executing!.

Comment: Why? Really, just why?

Comment: @podiluska I want to pass it as a parameter

Comment: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Pick a more appropriate tool. I'm almost certain that you're not calling this SQL directly via an HTTP request - there's got to be something sitting between the browser and the database server (a "web server", maybe?) and it's bound to have better support for generating HTML than the database has.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks! But I need the whole process need to be done in database(Sql server) Without involving any too

Comment: If someone asked for help in repairing fine antique furniture, but they're having difficulty deciding whether to drive the masonry screws using a rock or a hammer, would you try to help them work it out or would you try to point out that their whole approach seems to be wrong-headed?

Comment: Downvoted because no one ever has a vaild reason to do this. This is a terrible IDEA and new users/inexperience users shouldn't see this in search results

Comment: @gh9 I have tried this,and am successfully resolved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this helps you but...

once upon a time, I needed to send the query result as an html table in email body. I prepared myself a script that may not be the best but you do not have to change it a lot to make it work on any query you want.

Just bare in mind that if exists query must be the same that your actual query for html table, and that abstract query that list headers must have the same number of columns that your query  (that is lame, i know. I could have query into temp table and ask information schema for column names but i was satisfied with what i get and did not want to spend more time on this)

```
declare @table xml

if exists ( select  top 3 status, 
                    name, 
                    createdate
            from    sys.sysusers
            where   altuid = 1 )
begin

    --CAUTION!
    --query that creates table headers and query that creates content must have the same number of fields


    --create table with data
    set @table = ( --table formating
                   select '1' as '@border',
                          '3' as '@cellpadding',
                          '0' as '@cellspacing',
                          ( --table header formating
                            select 'center' as '@align',
                                   'font-weight: bold; background-color:silver' as '@style',
                                   ( --abstract entry with table headers
                                     select 1 as Tag,
                                            null as Parent,
                                           'status' as [tr!1!td!element],
                                           'name' as [tr!1!td!element],
                                           'createdate' as [tr!1!td!element]
                                     for    xml explicit,
                                                type
                                   )
                            for xml path('tbody'),
                                    type
                          ),
                          ( --actual query
                            select top 3
                                   1 as Tag,
                                   null as Parent,
                                   status as [tr!1!td!element],
                                   name as [tr!1!td!element],
                                   convert(nvarchar(19), createdate, 120) as [tr!1!td!element]
                            from   sys.sysusers
                            where   altuid = 1
                            for    xml explicit,
                                       type
                          )
                   for    xml path('table')
                 )
end

select @table
```

that will give you nice html table script like below

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody align="center" style="font-weight: bold; background-color:silver">
    <tr>
      <td>status</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>createdate</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>public</td>
    <td>2003-04-08 09:10:42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>db_owner</td>
    <td>2003-04-08 09:10:42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>db_accessadmin</td>
    <td>2003-04-08 09:10:42</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you can change @table type from xml to varchar and then simply add some extra oppening and closing html tags you need.

take care

Comment: BTW, I have tested this on MSSQL 2012, but should work on 2008 and 2005 I quess